# Unable to add data in Azure Open AI Studio

Tags: azure, azure-openai

I'm getting error 'We couldn't upload your data This request is not authorized to perform this operation.  Request ID - XXXX, Time - xxxxxx' while trying to 'Upload files'  in Azure Open AI service. I want to upload a word document so the model can read it and answer questions based on it.
I went to 'Add your data' in  OI Studio > selected 'Upload file' > Selected 'Blob storage account' > Selected 'Azure Cognitive Search Resource' > entered the 'Index name' > uploaded but got the attached error.

Error -1:

[image]

Error-2 :

[image]

Unable to proceed with this option

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting the error 'We couldn't upload your data This request is not authorized to perform this operation. Request ID - XXXX, Time - xxxxxx' while trying to 'Upload files' in Azure Open AI service.

The above error occurs when you don't have permission to perform the operation.

For uploading files in Azure Open AI Studio either you need **`Contributor`** role or **`Cognitive Services OpenAI Contributor`**.

You can assign it by

***Portal ->subscription ->Access control(IAM) -> Add role assignments -> Add role to your resource.***

[image]

Once, I assigned the role to the resource I can able to upload files to the Azure open AI studio.

[image]

**Blob storage:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Use your own data with Azure OpenAI service - Azure OpenAI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/use-your-data-quickstart?tabs=command-line&pivots=programming-language-studio)